# Merge objects with $push in MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregate:

```
[ 
  { $unwind: "$stocks" },
  { $sort: { date: 1 } },
  { $group:
    { 
      _id: { userId: "$userId", productId: "$stocks.productId" },
      stock: { $last: "$stocks" },
      lastDate: { $last: "$date" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.userId",
      stocks: { $push: { stock: "$stock", lastDate: "$lastDate" } }
    }
  }
]
```

It generates these documents:

```
{
  "_id": "5e75f498359fc8159d5b6075",
  "stocks": [
    {
      "stock": {
        "productId": "5e75eae1359fc8159d5b6073",
        "quantity": 20
      },
      "lastDate": "2020-03-21T16:21:14.008Z"
    },
    {
      "stock": {
        "productId": "5e75eaea359fc8159d5b6074",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      "lastDate": "2020-03-21T15:59:31.615Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

It works well but I want each items in the stocks to be "1-level" deep:

```
{
  "_id": "5e75f498359fc8159d5b6075",
  "stocks": [
    {
      "productId": "5e75eae1359fc8159d5b6073",
      "quantity": 20
      "lastDate": "2020-03-21T16:21:14.008Z"
    },
    {
      "productId": "5e75eaea359fc8159d5b6074",
      "quantity": 1
      "lastDate": "2020-03-21T15:59:31.615Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you help me update my aggregate to achieve the desired output?

EDIT: Here is a sample document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e7604e8645bb946e7eba6b5"),
  "date": "2020-03-21T12:13:28.355Z",
  "userId": ObjectId("5e75d985359fc8159d5b6072"),
  "stocks": [
    {
      "productId": ObjectId("5e75eae1359fc8159d5b6073"),
      "quantity": 5
    },
    {
      "productId": ObjectId("5e75eaea359fc8159d5b6074"),
      "quantity": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input document?

Comment: Try another `{ $unwind: "$stocks" }` at the end.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I added a sample document. It doesn't work with another `$unwind` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last `$group` to this:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id.userId",
    stocks: {
      $push: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$stock",
          {
            "lastDate": "$lastDate"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yyNIueUqQXK)